# Sum selected rows in datatable only?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable which has an amount column & a status column. I want to sum only those rows who have status '1'. How to do this? I am summing the column via datatable Compute method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
dataTable.Compute("sum(amount)", "status = 1")
```

Comment: Hi, that was quick. Thanks thelost ! I am having a little problem. My status datacolumn is a boolean. I am having error "Object cannot be cast from dbNull to other types"

CompTab.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IsRep", typeof(bool)));
CompTabRow["IsRep"] = true;
.......
total = Convert.ToDecimal(CompTab.Compute("SUM(Share)", "IsRep=false"));

Comment: Edit: Sorry, my bad. I found there were no innitial rows inside datatable matching the criteria.